# Applesoft Basic, how to hide the flashing cursor?

Tags: basic, apple-ii

I’ve finally decided to build a monthly budget program for an Apple //e, coming along nicely. Right now I’m using the AppleWin emulator.

Anyone know how to hide the cursor in Applesoft Basic? I was thinking of either hiding it using a Poke or change the cursor character to a blank space?

I know that VisiCalc does this, when you load the program, there is no flashing cursor until you begin editing. I want to do this same feature in my program.

Note: I don’t want to do it through the emulator as I will eventually move this to Apple hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this here. [Terminal control/Hiding the cursor](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Hiding_the_cursor#Applesoft_BASIC).

I was able to hide the cursor using the WAIT command, then grab the next character with GET.

```
WAIT 49152, 128
GET I$
```

More examples here: [Applesoft Basic Examples](http://www.virtualbasic.org/art-19-tit-Draw-paint-program-using-paddle-)

Answer (score 1):

VisiCalc is written in assembly language, and so is Applesoft BASIC - and so is the firmware routine that Applesoft calls to get a key while flashing the cursor. You can read the keyboard without flashing the cursor from Applesoft or assembly language, but you need to learn the underlying soft-switches used to do this.

```
Name     Hex    Decimal  Negative
KBD      $C000  49152    -16384
KBDSTRB  $C010  49168    -16368
```

In summary, you read KBD to get the value of the last key pressed. Bit 8 of that value (the 'strobe') will be set if it's a new key - in which case you need to subtract 128 to get the key value. You then access KBDSTRB to clear the strobe bit of KBD. For more details I refer you to page 5 of the [Apple II Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/Apple_II_Reference_Manual_1979_Apple) or page 12 of the [Apple IIe Technical Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIe_Technical_Reference_Manual).

Another good book which talks about this and many other things is [The New Apple II User's Guide](https://macgui.com/newa2guide/).

Here's a simple example of how to use these soft-switches:

```
10 KEY = PEEK (-16384) : REM READ KEY
20 IF KEY >= 128 THEN PRINT PEEK (-16368) : REM CLEAR STROBE
30 GOTO 10
```

Finally, consider visiting [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

There is a undocumented way to do this on Apple IIe

```
POKE 2043, ASC(" ") + 128
```

More info: https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue90/Feedback_Custom_Cursor.php

**Update**

As @Nick Westgate said. This works for Apple IIc and not for Apple IIe.

More info: https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin/issues/135

Comment: Yea I’m not using 80-col, this doesn’t seem to work using 40-column.

Comment: Yes and I found that the emulator doesn't support it either.
https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin/issues/135

Comment: So it looks like the emulator doesn't support the POKE 2043 trick in 40 column. But I am curious how VisiCalc accomplished this, when I load their rom into AppleWin there is not a flashing cursor?

Comment: I found some details about Visicalc: https://rmf.vc/implementingvisicalc
But none about the hidden cursor.

Comment: It turns out I [investigated this years ago](https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin/issues/135) and that feature is specific to the Apple IIc 80-column firmware. It doesn't work on either the original or enhanced Apple IIe.